# asp.net parameter from Master dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio

I have a dropdownlist in my master page, and a gridview in one of my content pages. I want to do sth like

```
   select * from table where ID=@ID
```

For parameter @ID, I want it from the dropdown list in the master page. I wonder how to achieve that?
Thanks very much for advice!

Comment: Paste some Code What you tried???

Comment: I assume there's not much coding? I can set manually in visual studio?  I know how to achieve that if dropdownlist is in the same page. but have no idea how to deal with a dropdownlist from master..

Answer (score 1):

Use following code to find dropdown in page load event of your page.

```
DropDownlist dropDownlist = (DropDownlist)this.Master.FindControl("YourDropDownId");
if(dropDownlist !=null)
{
      int Id =Convert.ToInt32(dropDownList.SelectedValue);
      //Write your grid binding logic here
 }
```

Use that Id in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Well, going from memory here, you *could* create a public property on your master page that returns the SelectedValue of the DropDownList control.  Then in your child page you can reference the Page.Master property of your child page.  Cast that page as whatever Type your master page is, and you will then be able to reference the property.

```
var ddlVal = (Page.Master as WhateverMyMasterPageClass).MyPublicProperty;
```

(That's C#, but maybe you get the picture.)

Answer (score 0):

To Expand on `@maelstrom` answer, this is what you will need to do:

**In master's code behind:**

```
public string DropDownValue
{
    get {
        return this. dropDownlist.selectedValue;
    }
    set {
        this.dropDownlist.selectedValue= value;
    }
}
```

**Get the value**

```
var myMaster = this.Master as YourMasterType;
if(myMaster != null)
{
   var Id = myMaster.DropDownValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of your advice!They are very helpful! I'm new to C# and even VB. My master has vb code
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

```
    Dim Selection As String = Nothing

    If Not DropDownList3.SelectedValue Is Nothing Then Selection = DropDownList3.SelectedValue
    Session("Selected") = Selection


End Sub
```

So in my asp content, I just find that I can manually set the source to be a session variable-- session("Selected"), say
          asp:SessionParameter Name="id" SessionField="Selected" 
and it works.